# WiX - Install Prerequisites and restart installer

Tags: wix

I am creating installer with WIX for VSTO addin.  During installation I need to install prerequisites, if they are not present. such as .NET4, SQL CE etc. However, since they need Admin rights, once they are installed the Addin is also registers under Admin account. So basically I have 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to force installer to quit after installing these packages and give meaningful message?
2. Is it possible to register Registry keys for user who launched the installer?

Boostrapper looks like this:

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="Netfx4Full"/>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="OpenXMLSDK"/>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="SQLServerCompact_4.0"/>
  <MsiPackage Id="MyApp" SourceFile="$(var.MyAddin.TargetPath)"/>
 </Chain>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Only with a custom BA.
2. Yes, as long as you're using an unelevated, per-user package.

Burn installs per-machine packages from an elevated helper process and per-user packages from an unelevated process. MSI 5.0 "swappable" packages and packages with ALLUSERS="" that require elevation are not supported as they can't be executed from an unelevated process.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I am not sure how the above answer answers to any of my questions :)